# perl logical OR operator

Tags: perl, or-operator

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$v = "test";
$v |= "best";
print $v;
$v =  "test" | "best";
print $v;
```

How the OR-ing is coming out here is not clear in second case(first case is oring with null seems to be clear ) ?

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

Comment: can you explain what is not clear?  note that `|` and `|=` are *not* logical or operators, they are bitwise or operators, a completely different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` is bitwise [operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) and you wan't to short-circuit string to variable, thus use logical OR `||`

```
$v ||= "best";
```

Bitwise calculation for first chars `"t" | "b"` is same as

```
#             116  | 98        = 118 ("v")
print chr(ord("t") | ord("b"));
```

Comment: Both are binary (taking two arguments) operators, neither is unary (taking one argument).  I think you meant `|` is a bitwise operator (bitwise OR) and `||` is a logical operator (logical OR).